# Upload AndroidStudio project on GitHub as a collaborator

Tags: android-studio, github, repository

i'm having a trouble with AndroidStudio and GitHub: I need to upload a project on a GitHub repository of which I'm collaborator. How can I do it? I know how to upload a project in a new repository but i don't know how to do that on a repository that's not mine. (I have commit rights). Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git
git add .
git commit -m "first - commit"
git push -u origin master
```